# Prove the following logarithm inequality.

Tags: inequality, logarithms, average

> If $x, y \in (0, 1)$ and $x+y=1$, prove that $x\log(x)+y\log(y) \geq \frac {\log(x)+\log(y)} {2}$.

I transformed the LHS to $\log(x^xy^y)$ and the RHS to $\log(\sqrt{xy})$, from where we get that $x^xy^y \ge \sqrt{xy}$ beacuse the logarithm is a monotonically increasing function. From there we can transfrom the inequality into $x^{x-y}y^{y-x} \ge 1$. So here I am stuck.

I could have started from some known inequalities too, like the inequalities between means.

Comment: Use $y=1-x$ and distinguish between the cases $x<1/2$ and $x>1/2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x-y$ and $\log x-\log y$ have the same sign, we have
$$
(x-y)(\log x-\log y)\ge 0
$$ or equivalently
$$
x\log x+y\log y\ge y\log x+x\log y.
$$ Hence it holds that
$$
 2x\log x+2y\log y\ge (x+y)\log x+(x+y)\log y=\log x+\log y.
$$ This proves
$$
 y\log y+x\log x\ge \frac{\log x+\log y}{2}.
$$

Note: As @Martin R pointed out, the result can be generalized to $$
x+y=1\Longrightarrow\; xf(x)+yf(y)\ge \frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2} 
$$ for any increasing function $f:(0,1)\to\Bbb R$.

Comment: The restriction $x \ge y$ seems to be unnecessary.

Comment: @MartinR Oh, yes you are right. I realized it in the middle of writing it. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: And the proof shows that $x+y=1$ implies $\frac{f(x)+f(y)}{2} \le x f(x) + yf(y) $ for *any* increasing function $f$ on $(0,1)$.

Comment: @MartinR Very nice generalization! I appreciate your valuable comments :)

Answer (score 1):

This can also be viewed as a special case of [Chebyshev's sum inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_sum_inequality).

For any increasing function $f:I \to \Bbb R$ and $x, y \in I$ we have
$$
 \frac 12 \bigl( x f(x) + y f(y) \bigr) \ge \left( \frac 12(x+y) \right) \cdot \left( \frac 12(f(x)+f(y)) \right) \\
\implies x f(x) + y f(y) \ge \frac{x+y}{2} (f(x) + f(y)) \, .
$$

More generally, if $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in I$ then
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n x_k f(x_k) \ge \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \sum_{k=1}^n f(x_k) \, .
$$